# Is there a way to force a WebView to update its Picture (view), while scrolling?

Tags: android, webview, scroll

If I run some javascript on a `WebView` while the `WebView` is being scrolled (with a finger on the screen), the view doesn't update with the new appearance until the finger is lifted from the device and the scroll stops.

To test this, I am overriding `onScroll` in the `WebView` and there I am calling some javascript which changes the background of the page to a random color. This gets called over and over while the page is scrolling. So it should rapidly flash different colors as you scroll.

However, on a Nexus S with Gingerbread and a Galaxy Nexus with Ice Cream Sandwich the color only updates when the scrolling stops.

But on a Xoom with Honeycomb, the color updates constantly as you are scrolling. This is the desired result.

Any ideas of what is different on the other devices and how to force the WebView to update itself while scrolling the way the Xoom did?

Thanks!

**More info:** Just to note, the javascript is received and enacted during scroll, but the picture showing these changes doesn't appear until scrolling is over. For example, if the javascript you call is "console.log('rawr');" the logs while appear while scrolling.

**Found something in the source code**  There is a `WebView` method called [startDrag()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/webkit/WebView.java#WebView.startDrag%28%29) that calls [WebViewCore.pauseUpdatePicture(mWebViewCore)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/webkit/WebViewCore.java#WebViewCore.pauseUpdatePicture%28android.webkit.WebViewCore%29) that disables the picture from being updated while scrolling. In 3.0 they introduced the WebSetting [setEnabledSmoothTransition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setEnableSmoothTransition%28boolean%29) which you can see in the 4.0 code, allows you to disable the pausing.  However, this is only available 3.0 and greater, which means less than 3% of in the wild devices.  So far I do not see any way to get around this in devices before 3.0..... :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when android 2.x versions were scrolled, to make it faster the screen was turned into a bitmap and that is scrolled, instead of re-drawing each view that may potentially be on the screen. so unless you override this, the colours are going to stop being drawn until the scrolling stops

Comment: The strange thing is that I have 3.1 on a Xoom and it works exactly as I want it to. So perhaps they changed how they did it, then changed it back, and then changed it back the other way again.  Any ideas on how to "ovveride this"?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OnTouchListener to intercept the finger action on the scroll bar, redraw your graphics and then pass the finger motion back to the scroll bar before exiting the onTouchListener.

Comment: How would you redraw the graphics? I want the Webview to redraw its content, the web content.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is to implement an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) for your WebView int the onTouchEvent call yourWebView.[invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29)();
This forces the View to redraw itself.

Comment: I tried this with some hope, but alas invalidate() doesn't seem to force the WebView to redraw its picture, it still waits until the scrolling finishes.